# Wordpress Cookie to show certain code / shortcode once per visit

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cookies, session-cookies, browser-cache

trying to solve this one and it's a doosey.

**Basically I have a typeform popup show once specific pages to get feedback from users but it currently loads every time the page loads.**

Would much rather users just see it once per visit.

I tried this with no luck:

```html
<style type="text/css">
div#slider {
    /* Hide the div */
    display: none;
}

.typeform-share{
display:none;
}
</style>

<div class="slider"><a class="typeform-share button" href="https://sombees.typeform.com/to/xxxxx" data-mode="popup" data-auto-open=true data-hide-headers=true data-hide-footer=true data-submit-close-delay="0" target="_blank"> </a> <script> (function() { var qs,js,q,s,d=document, gi=d.getElementById, ce=d.createElement, gt=d.getElementsByTagName, id="typef_orm_share", b="https://embed.typeform.com/"; if(!gi.call(d,id)){ js=ce.call(d,"script"); js.id=id; js.src=b+"embed.js"; q=gt.call(d,"script")[0]; q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q) } })() </script></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var cookie = document.cookie;
if (cookie.indexOf('visited=', 0) == -1) {
    var expiration = new Date();
    expiration.setDate(expiration.getDate()+1);
    document.cookie = 'visited=1;expires=' + expiration + ';path=/';

    var element = document.getElementById('slider');
    element.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked Typeform Embed API (https://developer.typeform.com/embed/)?

Using it you should be able to programmatically display or not the popup.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about Typeform, but testing this out I figured out what is wrong with your code.

So first of all you should wrap it in something like:

`$(window).on('load', function(){ ... }`

Now, second and most important thing is that Typeform does not display overlay or modal in the `slider` div, but in a newly created div which it puts at the end of the page.

[image]

Like you see in he picture above. In my case class of the div is `.jktBHD` but this can be different for you. I don't know.

So, knowing this you should change your code to something like this:

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){
    var cookie = document.cookie;
    if (cookie.indexOf('visited=', 0) == -1) {
        var expiration = new Date();
        expiration.setDate(expiration.getDate()+1);
        document.cookie = 'visited=1;expires=' + expiration + ';path=/';
        
        
        //
        // THE IMPORTANT PART
        //
        var element = document.querySelector('.jktBHD');
        element.style.display = 'block';

    }
})
```

```html
<style type="text/css">
    .jktBHD {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

I tested this out and it works for me. Hope it will work for you too.